# Inserting an object into an array field and only return the inserted object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the document below, and I wanted to add an object in the matches array and return only it and not the entire document, is it possible to do this with MongoDB?

```
 {
            "_id": "25113",
            "title": "Jogo de futebol",
            "rounds": {
                "matches": [{
                        "firstParticipant": {
                            "address": "789",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        },
                        "secondParticipant": {
                            "address": "748569874",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "firstParticipant": {
                            "address": "963",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        },
                        "secondParticipant": {
                            "address": "741",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "firstParticipant": {
                            "address": "258",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        },
                        "secondParticipant": {
                            "address": "789",
                            "battlesWon": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

My code:

```
const player = {
      firstParticipant: {
        address: '74125',
        battlesWon: 0,
      },
      secondParticipant: {
        address: '963258',
        battlesWon: 0,
      },
    };
    const result = await this.tournamentModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: '25113',
        status: 'OPEN',
      },
      { $addToSet: { 'rounds.matches': player } },
      { returnOriginal: false },
    );
```

the problem is that the **result** returns the entire document and not just the object added to the array.

Comment: Do you already have any code written to tackle your question - We do not have enough code information/context to work with and help you with here.

Comment: What is the code you wrote to return the result?

Comment: Why not return `player` if the update is successful?